# Dapper to return a model(property class) on DML operations

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

I am trying to implement caching on our database transaction and I want them to add,update and delete from cache as equivalent database operations happen.

```
public class ModelExample
{
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string site { get; set; }
}
```

say I have a method that inserts into the table

```
int result;
string query = "insert into modeltable(code,description,site) values (@code,@description,@site);
DynamicParameters parameter = new DynamicParameters();
parameter.Add("@code", code, DbType.String);
parameter.Add("@description", description, DbType.String);
parameter.Add("@site", site, DbType.String);
                connection.Open();
result = await connection.ExecuteAsync(query, parameter)
```

I want the result to actual return the ModelClass, instead of an integer. So basically, I want the results of the insert so that i can add it to the cache.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case of MS SQL you can use `OUTPUT` clause to access to inserted row:

```
[Test]
public async Task DapperOutputClauseUsage()
{
    // Arrange
    var conn = new SqlConnection("YourDatabaseConnectionString");
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    var ex = new ModelExample
    {
        code = "code",
        description = "description",
        site = "site"
    };

    // Act
    var result = await conn.QuerySingleAsync<ModelExample>(@"INSERT INTO ModelTable(code, description, site)
                                                             OUTPUT INSERTED.*
                                                             VALUES (@code, @description, @site)", ex);
    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(result.code, ex.code);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.description, ex.description);
    Assert.AreEqual(result.site, ex.site);

}

public class ModelExample
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string site { get; set; }
}
```

If you have `IDENTITY` on your primary key, it will be returned as well. You just need to add `Id` property to your model class. You can also use `OUTPUT INSERTED.*` and `OUTPUT DELETED.*` with `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries to get access to changes in a row. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @KozhevnikovDmitry . but unfortunately, these tables have triggers and i cant have an output statement in my DML statements

Comment: Please provide an example of trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to `select` parameters after `insert into` values. 
then use  `QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<TModel>` to execute SQL get the model.

```
string SQLStatement = @"insert into modeltable(code,description,site) values (@code,@description,@site)

SELECT @code code,
        @description description,
        @site site";

ModelExample model = connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<ModelExample>(SQLStatement,parameter).Result;
```

Comment: Yeah sure, but i dont want to add the extra layer of doing the select again.